# Install phpMyAdmin for remote access

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, phpmyadmin

I use Ubuntu 20.04, and using a remote MySql DB (which is installed on an external server).

I am looking for installing phpMyAdmin without installing a local MySql server, but cannot find how to do it. Is is possible?

Alternatively, I could install a different gui, if there is any good and simple one.

Answer (score 1):

You install it via command:

```
sudo apt install phpmyadmin php-mbstring php-zip php-gd php-json php-curl
```

And in `config.inc.php` you should change there lines:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'HostName:port'; 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'userName'; 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'Password'; 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
```